# LotusScript - Find documents by subject

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Hello i wrote this code (copying from sites i found online) to find emails in my Inbox view of lotus notes and save the attachments.
What i cannot do is to find the docs with the subject i need. The collection is not populated. Where am i wrong? Thanks.

```
Sub Initialize
Dim sess As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim coll As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As Variant
Dim filename As Variant

Const DIR_NOT_FOUND = 76
Dim i As Integer
Dim strname As String
Dim view As NotesView
Dim myArray (1 To 2) As String
myArray (1) = "DataToBeSaved"
myArray (2) = "DataToBeSaved"

Set db = sess.currentdatabase
Set view = db.GetView("($Inbox)" )

Set coll = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(myArray,False)
Set doc = coll.GetFirstDocument()

While Not doc Is Nothing
    Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
    If Not rtitem Is Nothing Then
        If ( rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
            If Isempty(rtitem.EmbeddedObjects) = False Then
                Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
                    If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then
                        filename = Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc)
                        'For i = 0 To Ubound(filename)
                        If (filename(i)="query nas.txt") Then
                            strname = Replace(filename(i), "/", "-")
                            On Error DIR_NOT_FOUND Resume Next
                            Call o.ExtractFile( "\\rflenas1.rfle.roto-frank.com\RFIB\LOTUSPROVA\" & strname )
                        End If                          
                        'Next
                        doc.fieldname = ""
                        Call doc.Save( True, True )
                    End If
                End Forall
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set doc = coll.getnextdocument(doc)
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to add a check for doc.Subject(0) = "SUBJECT YOU WANT TO FIND".

Comment: So i don't have to use GetAllDocumentsByKey? So, What's the key?

Comment: doc.Subject does not exists in my Lotus

Comment: After your `While doc is not Nothing` add `if doc.subject(0) = "SUBJECT TO MATCH" then`  and then put `end if` before `set doc = coll.getnextdocument(doc)`.

Explanation: `doc.subject(0)` means get the string value of the subject field in the doc

Comment: Did you use the loop in my answer?  That will look at each document.  Your original loop only looks at documents that are in the collection, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your logic in a loop like this.  It will loop round all of the documents in your inbox and if the subejct matches, it will do whatever you want to put in the "Do something with the doc" area.

```
set doc = view.getfirstdocument
while not doc is nothing
    if doc.subject(0) = "THE SUBJECT I WANT TO FIND" then
    'Do something with the doc
end if
    set doc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
Wend
```

You will no longer need the `coll`

Comment: I used a collection because i search only in UNread documents. If i search entire view or db it's very very very slow

Comment: You can still loop through a collection, but you have to test doc.Subject().  There is no "key" in the Inbox folder because it isn't a sorted view. GetAllDocumentByKey searches the first sorted column.  And BTW, there is an unprocessed documents collecction (look int the documentiaton for the NotesDatabase class), but (as far as I can remember) there isn't a collection for unread documents.